# Primefaces extensions tooltip convert number

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tooltip, primefaces-extensions

I have a p:dataTable with a pe:toolTip appended for all cells. The tooltip text is displaying ok, but it doesnt apply the f:convertNumber format that I have for my table cells:

My columns look like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{informeAux.vagonesKm}" title="#{informeAux.vagonesKm}">
    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2"/>
</h:outputText>
```

And the number in the table looks like this:  11.335,40 but the Tooltip displays the value like this: 11335.4 (Number is not formatted)

Haven't found a way to properly display it, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the converter attribute for  the `<pe:tooltip>` but couldn't get it working.

In the end I made a separate property 'vagonesKmTitle' and applied the decimal format in my bean.

```
<h:outputText value="#{informeAux.vagonesKm}" title="#{informeAux.vagonesKmTitle}">
                                                <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2"/>
                                            </h:outputText>
```